# How do I call a vector of type class inside another class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, vector

I was given the main and told to create a program in response to the main using 3 classes. An amusement park class, a rider class, and a ride class.
I want to add a rider to a vector of rides and store that vector in a vector of amusement parks. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Rider
{
string name;
int height;
public:
    Rider(string name, int height)
    {
        this->name=name;
        this->height=height;
    }
    Rider(int height)
    {
        this->height=height;
    }
};
class Ride
{
    public:
    vector <Rider> all_riders;
};
class Amusement_park
{
    vector <Ride> all_rides;
    public:
        Amusement_park(int numRides)
        {
            all_rides[numRides];
        }
        vector <Rider> get_ride(int whichRide)
        {
            vector <Ride> the_ride= all_rides[whichRide];
            return the_ride;
        }
        void add_line(class Rider)
        {
            the_ride.pushback(Rider);
        }
};
int main()
{
    Rider r1("Yaris",45);   //name, height in inches
    Rider r2(49);           //height in inches
    Amusement_park a1(3);  //3 is the number of rides in the park
    a1.get_ride(1).add_line(r1); //add a rider to the line of a ride
    Amusement_park a2(2); //2 is the number of rides in the park
    a2.get_ride(1).add_line(r2); //add a rider to the line of a ride
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a name to the `Ride` class.  Most rides in amusement parks have names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give some advices for your code, and one (or more) of them will presumably solve problems you might have.

First, always try to use constructor *initializer lists* when possible. Usually, when the constructor is obvious as is yours, using such a list is trivial. In this case, you could just do:

```
    class Rider
    {
    string name;
    int height;
    public:
        Rider(string name, int height) : name(name), height(height) {}
        Rider(int height) : height(height) {}
    };
```

and the same for the rest of your trivial constructors.

Now, if you take a closer look at your c'tor for `Amusement_park` class, you will see that you try to access an index in your `vector` that hasn't been, let's say, defined yet. That is, you have an *empty* vector that is supposed to hold objects of `Ride` type, but since it is empty, trying to access its content (whatever index you might try to reach) is what we call *undefined behavior*. That's a piece of memory that you don't know what it holds, and that's because you never told your compiler how many `Ride` objects will be in there so that your program could properly allocate memory and initialize objects for you there. In order for you to actually create a vector of the appropriate size, or, more precisely, properly resize your vector, your `Amusement_park` c'tor should be something like

```
Amusement_park(int numRides)
    {
        all_rides.resize(numRides);
    }
```

Your `get_ride` function inside Amusement_park is also not very good.
Actually, your whole statement `a1.get_ride(1).add_line(r1)` isn't doing what you are intending to.
First, the `get_ride()` function returns a `vector` of `Rider`, which doesn't have an `add_line()` member function. You actually want it to return a `Amusement_park` object, which is the only one in your code that has such a member function. However, returning it is not logical, as you might see.

In short, your code contains many flaws, both language as logically speaking.
Hence, I recommend that you:
1) Double check the logic of your code;
2) Get a nice tutorial book on C++ to start on.

Good luck!

Comment: I've fixed some things according to what you said, and now I only have one error message. I moved the add_line function into my Ride class. I'm now getting an error that says [error: 'Rider' does not refer to a value all_riders.push_back(Rider); ]

Comment: Did you modify your `get_ride()` function inside `Amusement_park`? it should return a `Ride` object, not a `vector<Rider>` as it is in your code. For this, all you need to do is to modify the return type and then return the value `all_rides[whichRide]`. Then you could call the function `add_line()` inside the `Ride` class through the object returned by your `get_ride()` function. Also, what line your compiler is pointing to when raising that error message?

Comment: Also, the parameter of your `add_line()` function is not correct. `Rider` is a type by itself, defined by you, actually. So, your function, logically, should expect a variable with type `Rider`, and hence its declaration should be `void add_line(Rider riderId)`, where riderId is the variable name, and Rider is its type. Then, you push riderId to your vector as usual.

Comment: I did what you said and the error was pointing to the add_line function inside my Ride class. That second comment just solved it. I was using (class Rider) as my parameter instead of (Rider (variable name)). Thank you!

Comment: I think that this will fix your problem at hand. However, please try to follow my 2nd suggestion/recommendation. There are plenty of good options here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list]

Answer (score 0):

In your function `add_line(class Rider)`, there is no reference of `the_ride` to push the rider. You can pass the `vector<Rider>` you get from `get_ride(int whichRide)` to the function or you can just combine the get_ride and add_line to one function like this:

```
void add_rider_to_line(int whichRide, class Rider)
{
    all_rides[whichRide].push_back(Rider);
}
```